# I'm getting Error: Please Use Column Names for 'x'

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm attempting to partition a dataset generated using principal component analysis (into a training + testing set) and then calculate the accuracy.

However, I'm running into this error:

```
Error: Please use column names for `x`
```

I'm using the starwars dataset from dplyr for this example, and my partitioning code is here (after doing PCA):

```
# Partition the data
index = createDataPartition(y=star.pc$gender, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
# Everything in the generated index list
train_set = gender[index,]
# Everything except the generated indices
test_set = gender[-index,]
```

I then try the following which replicates the above error:

```
#Fitting the model using the training set
svm_split <- train(gender ~., data = train_set, method = "svmLinear")
```

I think it has to do with the logical operators (i.e., commas?) in the way I'm creating the train_set and test_set. Or, some issue with there being no predictors when I partition the data. But I'm unsure how to do it differently.

None of the previous posts on this error seem to match my issue.